# Reuse of SQL Server Product Key for installing developer tools at workstations

Tags: sql-server, license-key

At my workplace we just upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2 Advanced in our development server using the product key of the MSDN subscription, and we want to install the full developer tools (Management Studio & Profiler) in several workstations as we had with the 2005 edition.

The problem is that the setup of the 2008 edition ask for a product key before selecting the components that you want to install, and we want to know if is allowed using the same key that we used for the server just for installing the developer tools.

If not, there is a way on installing (legally) the SQL Server Profiler in several workstations without having a different key for each one? (we only have a couple of keys from the the MSDN subscription).

Comment: I think this question would be better asked of Microsoft Sales.  IANAL, but "Someone on stackoverflow told me I could" is not indemnification against a lawsuit.

Comment: Of course, but I was looking for some hints like the link provided in the answer (I tried google first but sometimes my search-fu is pretty weak...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.   I think it's pretty clear that MSFT expects each developer to have their own MSDN Subscription:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx

> MSDN subscriptions are licensed on a per-user basis.  One person can use the software to design, develop, test, or demonstrate his or her programs on any number of devices.  Each person who uses the software this way needs a license.

I think it's OK to have developers running just express editions, but they shouldn't be taking advantage of any MSDN benefits they don't have a subscription for.   As Chris stated, you should probably ask your sales rep if you think sharing tools like the profiler might be OK.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that. To be in the safe side, for know we are going to use Management Studio Express at workstations and connect via Terminal Services to the server when we need to use the Profiler.